# How make a dynamic drawable in android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a drawable with two ids and I need to instantiate this drawable, but I need each one to have different parameters. For example, one I want the color of the ring with id = id_1 to be red and the other blue.

**My drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_1">
        <shape android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="8"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#E3DEDE"></solid>

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_2">
        <shape android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="8"
            android:useLevel="true">
            <solid android:color="#ffff00"></solid>

        </shape>
    </item>
    
</layer-list>
```

**My code**

```
Drawable drawable = itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.level_up);
```

Comment: Good start! Cast that `drawable` to `LayerDrawble` and continue

Comment: Do you know how I can get the ids and set it ?

Comment: Once you have cast it as a LayerDrawable you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable#findDrawableByLayerId(int) to look up layers by id